# Send Multiple Emails with MvcMailer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email, mvcmailer

I am developing an MVC 3 project and would like to send invoices out to clients each month by email. How would I send out these multiple emails, and if a loop, how would I code this loop?

Here is my InvoiceMailer code:

```
    public virtual MailMessage InvoiceMailed()
    {
        var invoices = db.Invoice.FirstOrDefault();
        var client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault();


        var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "InvoiceMailed"};

        mailMessage.To.Add("amecily@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(client.EmailAddress);
        ViewBag.Name = client.FullName;
        ViewBag.Number = invoices.InvoiceNumberID;
        ViewBag.Amount = invoices.InvoiceAmount;
        ViewBag.Month = invoices.InvoiceMonth;
        PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "InvoiceMailed");

        return mailMessage;

    }
```

And the view for my email:

```
Hello @ViewBag.Name
<br /><br />
This is your invoice from DFP Productions for the month of @ViewBag.Month
<br /><br />
@ViewBag.Number<br />
@ViewBag.Amount<br />
@ViewBag.Month<br />
```

The email is currently sending, but obviously only with one set of information and only sends to two of three recipients (is this due to FirstOrDefault and what should I use instead?).

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: Okay cool, so FirstOrDefault is when you only want the first element in a sequence. What would I put if I want all the elements? I'm very new to MVC and C#

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic would be

- Get the set of clients to be billed.
- instantiate an instance of [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx), connecting to your MTA
- For each client in the set,

  - compute their invoice data
  - construct an instance of MailMessage as appropriate, using the client and the client's invoice data.
  - Post the message via your SmtpClient instance
- Dispose of the SmtpClient instance (and any other IDisposables that are no longer needed.)